# uniqueness in array column type throughout all records

Tags: postgresql, array

There is a table

```
id serial primary key,
names varchar(20)[]
```

it contains such record

```
1, {"one", "two", "three"}
```

Then, next record is inserting (notice `one` array element already exists in existing record)

```
2, {"four", "one"}
```

or existing record is updated by adding one more element to the array, but such string element is already used in some other record.

Is it possible to create a unique constraint which wouldn't allow repeating elements inside arrays globaly throughout all rows and not just inside the array value itself?

Comment: Why don't you normalize your model? Then you can add a unique index.

Comment: that is a known solution, whereas I just wanted to clarify to myself whether it is possible with array collumn

Answer (score 1):

An **[exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)** would seem like the weapon of choice:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_names_overlap EXCLUDE USING gist (names WITH &&);
```

Alas, as of Postgres 11, still no GiST indexes for arrays. And GIN indexes are not (yet) allowed to implement exclusion constraints. There is a [TODO item](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Indexes) *"Allow GIN indexes to be used for exclusion constraints"*, but I wouldn't know of any recent progress.

There would be a way with `integer` numbers after installing the additional module [intarray - which provides GiST operator classes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html#id-1.11.7.27.7). So if your "numbers" are actual numbers ...

Else, here is a **workaround** I came up with some years ago:

- [Can PostgreSQL have a uniqueness constraint on array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017013/939860)

Answer (score 0):

You could make this with another table (where each row will be an ID and a single name) with a composite PK, but using an ARRAY is not possible.